# Read .dat file using python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I've got a simulation involving internal waves and moving particles in the water, using the *MITgcm*. The output of this looks something like this for each time step:

```
   -9999 0.0000000000000000000  #Time step (0.00000000000000 seconds)
 1308.2021183321899       -14.999709364517091 # Particle 1 (X,Z)
 1308.2020142528656       -24.999521595698688 # Particle 2 (X,Z)
 1308.2018600072618       -34.999345597877536 # .
 1308.2016593336587       -44.999185870669805 # .
 1308.2014165588744       -54.999046508237896 # .
 1308.2011370083103       -64.998931076248894
 1308.2008269116873       -74.998842490305705
 1308.2004933548124       -84.998782925797485
 1308.2001441978532       -94.998753764086956
 1308.1997879652938       -104.99875557384759
 1308.1994336881464       -114.99878812280582
 1308.1990906721119       -124.99885041328211
 1308.1987681881285       -134.99894073461562
 1308.1984750963150       -144.99905672694641
 1308.1982194336249       -154.99919545294702
 1308.1980080134056       -164.99935347476733
 1308.1978461242272       -174.99952693694112
 1308.1977378137256       -184.99971163492469
 1308.2000000000000       -195.00000000000000
 5232.8000000000002       -15.000038916290352
 5232.8000000000002       -25.000064153684303
 5232.8000000000002       -35.000089286157163
 5232.8000000000002       -45.000114270293523
 5232.8000000000002       -55.000139061712051 # Particle 57
```

Where -9999 #number is the time step (in seconds), left column is X position and right column is Z position (in meters); and every line is a different particle (except the -9999 one). So we'll have an enormous amount of lines with something like this for every time step and every particle.

I would like to plot the time-evolution of the position of my particles. How can I do it? If that's too hard, I would be happy with static plots of different time-steps with all particles position.

Thank you so much.

Edit1: What I tried to do is this, but I didn't show it before because it is far from proper:

```
 from matplotlib import numpy
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
 plot.plot(*np.loadtxt('data.dat',unpack=True), linewidth=2.0)
```

or this:

```
 plot.plotfile('data.dat', delimiter=' ', cols=(0, 1), names=('col1', 'col2'), marker='o')
```

Comment: You could use `numpy.loadtxt` to read in all of your data (if it fits in memory), then do the post-processing. Since the number of particles is probably fixed, this shouldn't be too difficult. You should filter out the lines for time points, then `reshape` the rest into 57-element blocks.

Comment: That sounds great. But I'm afraid that I don't know how to do it. I am surely not an expert or too skilled at these fields.

Comment: Do you have an output file for every time step? Or is it all in one file?

Comment: It kinda sounds like you are asking for someone to write this for you.  StackOverflow is not a code-writing service.  What have you attempted so far, show your work so we can see where you've gone wrong.

Comment: All the data is all in just one file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `numpy.loadtxt` for reading input, but only because post-processing would also need numpy. You can read all your data to memory, then find the separator lines, then reshape the rest of your data to fit your number of particles. The following assumes that none of the particles ever reach *exactly* `x=-9999`, which should be a reasonable (although not foolproof) assumption.

```
import numpy as np
filename = 'input.dat'
indata = np.loadtxt(filename, usecols=(0,1)) # make sure the rest is ignored
tlines_bool = indata[:,0]==-9999
Nparticles = np.diff(np.where(tlines_bool)[0][:2])[0] - 1
# TODO: error handling: diff(np.where(tlines_bool)) should be constant
times = indata[tlines_bool,1]
positions = indata[np.logical_not(tlines_bool),:].reshape(-1,Nparticles,2)
```

The above code produces an `Nt`-element array `times` and an array `position` of shape `(Nt,Nparticles,2)` for each particle's 2d position at each time step. By computing the number of particles, we can let numpy determine the size of the first dimension (this iswhat the `-1` index in `reshape()` is for).

For plotting you just have to slice into your `positions` array to extract what you exactly need. In case of 2d `x` data and 2d `y` data, `matplotlib.pyplot.plot()` will automatically try to plot the columns of the input arrays as a function of each other. Here's an example of how you can visualize, using your actual input data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t_indices = slice(None,None,500)  # every 500th time step
particle_indices = slice(None)    # every particle
#particle_indices = slice(None,5)   # first 5 particles
#particle_indices = slice(-5,None)  # last 5 particles

plt.figure()
_ = plt.plot(times[myslice],positions[myslice,particle_indices,0])
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('x')

plt.figure()
_ = plt.plot(times[myslice],positions[myslice,particle_indices,1])
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('z')

plt.figure()
_ = plt.plot(positions[myslice,particle_indices,0],positions[myslice,particle_indices,1])
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('z')
plt.show()
```

[image: x(t) plot] [image: z(t) plot] [image: z(x) plot]

Each line corresponds to a single particle. The first two plots show the time-evolution of the `x` and `z` components, respectively, and the third plot shows the `z(x)` trajectories. Note that there are a lot of particles in your data that don't move at all:

```
>>> sum([~np.diff(positions[:,k,:],axis=0).any() for k in range(positions.shape[1])])
15
```

(This computes the time-oriented difference of both coordinates for each particle, one after the other, and counts the number of particles for which every difference in both dimensions is 0, i.e. the particle doesn't move.). This explains all those horizontal lines in the first two plots; these stationary particles don't show up at all in the third plot (since their trajectory is a single point).

I intentionally introduced a bit fancy indexing which makes it easier to play around with your data. As you can see, indexing looks like this: `times[myslice]`, `positions[myslice,particle_indices,0]`, where both slices are defined in terms of...well, a `slice`. You should look at the documentation, but the short story is that `arr[slice(from,to,stride)]` is equivalent to `arr[from:to:stride]`, and if any of the variables is `None`, then the corresponding index is empty: `arr[slice(-5,None)]` is equivalent to `arr[-5:]`, i.e. it will slice the final 5 elements of the array.

So, in case you use a reduced number of trajectories for plotting (since 57 is a lot), you might consider adding a legend (this only makes sense as long as the default color cycle of matplotlib lets you distinguish between particles, otherwise you have to either set manual colors or change the default color cycle of your axes). For this you will have to keep the handles that are returned from `plot`:

```
particle_indices = slice(None,5)   # first 5 particles
plt.figure()
lines = plt.plot(positions[myslice,particle_indices,0],positions[myslice,particle_indices,1])
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('z')
plt.legend(lines,['particle {}'.format(k) for k in range(len(t))])
plt.show()
```

[image: example with legend]

Comment: It worked perfectly except for one thing. It showed this way: https://postimg.org/image/q0kknqoon/

Is there something wrong?

Comment: Well, you might have a lot of particles which overlap. I assume it's simply hard to distinguish between particles (although I find that blue sea a bit odd). It's hard to produce a meaningful plot from this much data, but that is a different question:)

Comment: @AlejandroJiménezRico you should try plotting only a few particles to see what's going on, easily with `positions.T[:,:10]` to plot the first ten trajectories, or something similar.

Comment: I tried plotting a few particles and it look roughly the same. I didn't choose any colour, it just appeard like this copying exactly your code. Your pic is as clear as I wished to do.

Comment: @AlejandroJiménezRico those are a lot of time steps. That blue blackground can only come about if one of your particles is oscillating to and fro very rapidly (colours are automatically assigned to each trajectory). Try plotting your trajectories one by one, and try to find one that is behaving erratically. I mean, if one of your particles is much lighter, it could easily have much larger spread than the others, diffusing everywhere.

Comment: I plotted trajectories 1, 5, 7, 24, 33 and 55. They all look very similar (not exactly), with most of the pic blue and nothing meaningful or watchable.

Comment: @AlejandroJiménezRico Try plotting only number 5. The very first trajectory will automatically be blue (and some later ones as well, colours are reused). Try plotting the first 4 or 5 trajectories one at a time. These all have different colours in your original plots. Another option is to plot only  a subset of your time steps, skipping a few. Say, leave 20 or 50 time steps in total (if your particles diffuse, they should have fractal-like trajectories, which can look bad if the line plot has too thick lines).

Comment: I'm doing so and still the same. Is very confusing. Is there somthing wrong? I let you the full file to download, if you want to take a look: [link](https://webmail.csic.es/bigfiles/descarga.php?l=74640554b&t=1466510106&f=trajetories.dat)

Be careful, there are some comments at the start and at the end that you must erase if you want to read it.

Comment: @AlejandroJiménezRico thanks for the data, I found the stupidest of indexing errors imaginable. Sorry about that. I fixed the code, and added a sample plot based on your actual data. Please see my update.

Comment: It looks like a Pollock but it's great now, thank you so much. One last question: If I want to plot just a few particles, what would I have to change?

Comment: @Alejandro the 2d array `positions` contains the trajectory of each particle; it has `positions.shape==(57, 100000)`. In my example I plotted `positions[:,something]`, which sliced all the rows of `positions`. So, if you want to select a few trajectories, just index the first dimension of `positions` as well, such as `positions[:4,something]` or `positions[[0,14,25],something]` with an appropriate `something`. If you want to get every time step, `positions[[0,14,25],:]`. Look at `numpy` array indexing for more specifics.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116119/discussion-between-alejandro-jimenez-rico-and-andras-deak).

Comment: @AlejandroJiménezRico I'm even more tired than originally:D I completely messed up. I only now realized that your columns in the trajectories are for two separate dimensions, x and z. I understood this at first, but the time data confused me. Please stand by while I fix this once and for all:) See chat for details.