# python script converting .dat to json

Tags: python, json, numpy, matplotlib, graph

I have .dat file that I want to use in my script which draws scatter graph with data input from that .dat file. I have been manually converting .dat files to .csv for this purpose but I find it not satisfactory.
This is what I am using currently.

```
import pandas as pd import matplotlib.pyplot as plt import numpy as np

filename=raw_input('Enter filename ')
csv = pd.read_csv(filename)
data=csv[['deformation','stress']]
data=data.astype(float)
x=data['deformation']
y=data['stress']
plt.scatter(x,y,s=0.5)

fit=np.polyfit(x,y,15) 
p=np.poly1d(fit)
plt.plot(x,p(x),"r--")
plt.show()
```

Programmer friend told me that it would be more convenient to convert it to JSON and use it as such. How would I go about this?

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38082532/read-dat-file-using-python

Comment: What is a dat file? I dont think there is any standard for that? Next, what is the problem of your current approach? I don't think converting to JSON is of any help at all. But one can only judge on that if the input data format is known .

Comment: .dat file looks as such: 
"deformation","stress"
1.26449846,124
1.27635146,137
...

Answer (score 0):

try using the numpy read feature

```
import numpy as np

yourArray = np.fromfile('YourData.dat',dtype=dtype)

yourArray = np.loadtxt('YourData.dat')
```

loadtxt is more flexible than fromfile

Comment: If you assume this to be working, then `pd.read_csv("data.dat", ...)` would work as well... in which case there wouldn't actually be any problem in the first place.